# Wordpress - Post page breaking / not displaying properly and 'there has been a critical error' message displayed

Tags: wordpress

Post page on wordpress site is breaking when trying to view a post, example link: https://rockpoolrac.com/rockpool-reflections-june-2023/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCsum.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

debug log showing the following error hundreds of times:
PHP Deprecated:  The PSR-0 `Requests_...` class names in the Request library are deprecated. Switch to the PSR-4 `WpOrg\Requests\...` class names at your earliest convenience. in /home/rockpool/public_html/wp-includes/Requests/src/Autoload.php on line 171

Thanks

Have not tried any solutions yet.

Comment: Sorry, but this can't be answered here, as it requires some debug. I recommend reaching out to a professional developer who can assist you with fix this issue.